# What colors or wavelengths are photoresistors sensitive to?

Tags: ldr, light-sensor, sensitivity

Using an LDR or photoresistor, are they more sensitive to one color or wavelength compared to another, or are they consistent with any light? Why?

Comment: How is this not directly answered in the datasheet of whatever photoresistor you are looking at?

Comment: @olin apparently not all datasheet have them, and you'd have to know what you are looking for.

Comment: If you hadn't been someone who generally writes good posts and has earned some respect here, I'd have voted to close this.  As it is, you're on thin ice.  *Obviously* sensitivity will vary across the electromagnetic spectrum.  I still can't tell what specific device you are asking about.  Do you have a CdS cell?  How do you know if you don't have a datasheet?  This question is basically *"guess what I've got, then read me its datasheet"*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on [a random LDR's data sheet](http://www.biltek.tubitak.gov.tr/gelisim/elektronik/dosyalar/40/LDR_NSL19_M51.pdf), yes. A photoresistor's sensitivity is a byproduct of the chemical used to create it.

[image]

This one, a CdS cell, peaks around 545 nm wavelength, which means it is much more sensitive with Green, Green-Yellow light than it is UV/Violet/Blue or Red/IR. It's also fairs better along the higher wavelength colors, Yellow/Orange/Red, than it does with lower wavelength colors, Cyan/Blue, based on it's sharp decline to the lower wavelength.

It also depends on the ***type of LDR you are using***. Typical *visual light* LDRs use Cadmium-Sulfide, CdS. Other LDRs are IR range, based on Lead sulphide, PbS, or variants.

[image]

There are also variants of the CdS with different peak wavelength response, based on [this data sheet](http://www.gotronic.fr/pj-1284.pdf):

[image]

Cadmium Selenide, CdSe, peaks just outside of Red into InfraRed. Hybrid cells using both, Cadmium Sulfide Selenides, Cd(S-Se) range in the Orange and Red visible wavelengths.

**Notably, natural sunlight, while covering the entire visible spectrum, slightly peaks in the blue-green and green ranges, matching the peak response range of a CdS Photoresistor nicely.**

Comment: Which means that CdS is as good as useless for common IR LED wavelengths (so is CdS.Se, but not CdSe).  Of course most applications with an IR LED would use a photodiode anyway.